# Splitting list items to get only the values after the delimiter

Tags: python

I have a list like

```
['h : abcd', 'i : 467', 'gh578']
```

I want the output like

```
['abcd', '467', 'gh578']
```

How to do it using split?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a = ['h : abcd', 'i : 467', 'gh578']
[i.split(':')[-1].strip() for i in a]
```

it is okay to split `gh578` with `:`, but the trick is use `[-1]` to get the last one, and strip out space.

Answer (score 0):

regular expressions can do that without chained `str` calls in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [re.sub(".*:\s*","",x) for x in a]
['abcd', '467', 'gh578']
```

basically removing all what's behind colon, and possible spaces after that, to leave only the rest.